# Can't hide Registration link

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, authentication, modal-dialog

I am trying to hide the registration link "Non sei registration" in the login popup (Login Guide Alpine) on my website: https://www.guidealpine365.it/

I have tried with the CSS code below:

```
    .modal-content .sign-in-form .c27-open-modal > a[data-target="#sign-up-modal"] 
{
        display: none;
}
```

I just need to hide the Registration link from the popup.

Answer (score 0):

In frontend.css (https://www.guidealpine365.it/wp-content/themes/my-listing/assets/dist/frontend/frontend.css) set

`.modal-content form.sign-in-form a.c27-open-modal { display: none; }`

Comment: or you can make it more specific: ```.modal-content form.sign-in-form a.c27-open-modal[data-target="#sign-up-modal"] { display: none; }```

Comment: Thank you guys! I got lost in a little detail! Your help was appreciated!